# Proxy outgoing traffic via all ports to a single local port using iptables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, proxy

I have a linux machine, and there is a proxy server runs on this same machine listening 127.0.0.1:1080. I want to use `iptables` to achieve:

1. For all outgoing HTTP(S) requests via port 1080, direct connect without any processing
2. For all HTTP(S) requests from other ports, proxy through 127.0.0.1:1080
3. Incoming requests are not touched and received normally

You may wonder why I proxy the outgoing requests to itself, it's because the proxy server also does obfuscation and some other fancy stuff.

I've read many answers, but most of them are only interested in requests via/to some specific ports (e.g. 80), whereas I want all but one ports.

I know I can use commands like

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1080
```

But I guess this may simply result in a self-routing loop.

In [this blog](https://www.darkcoding.net/software/decrypt-your-https-traffic-with-mitmproxy/), the author provides a solution

> If you want to run the client on the same machine as the server (you’re in a coffee shop on your laptop; have a pastry for me), we can’t use the PREROUTING table, because it only applies to packets coming from outside. What we can do is modify the destination port on packets OUTPUT by our client process. The catch is that it will also affect packets output by mitmproxy, and we’ll get into a routing loop.
>
> There are probably several ways to solve this, but the one that worked for me was running mitmproxy as root, and making the iptables rule not apply to root-owned processes.
>
> `sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner root --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`
>
> - `-m owner`: Load the owner module.
> - `! –uid-owner root`: Rule does not apply to root-owned processes

But there is only one user `root` on my machine and I have no intention to create another one for this.

BTW, I'm not sure if I need to set `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` to 1 in this case.

You can assume the OS is a newly installed Ubuntu 20.04.

EDIT: Clarify the "traffic" refers to HTTP requests.

Comment: Are you talking about web traffic, or can your proxy do an unlimited number of different types of application processing? Or do you really mean to say that you want all your outbound traffic to go through a SOCKS proxy? If so, then `iptables` is not the right tool for the job

Comment: Yes, web traffic. I indeed want all outbound traffic to go through that proxy, so they can get processed (obfuscation, etc.). I tried some programs like `proxychains`, but I have more than one applications to handle. Setting environment variables is a solution, but not all applications respect that.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear you are only referring to web traffic. You might want to clarify that this is (or isn't) http and/or https

Comment: Edited, hope now it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Enable routing
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# Enable forwarding to loopback interface
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
# Forward all TCP  except TCP/1080
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp ! --dport 1080 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:1080
# Enable NAT (aka Masqurade)
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: In the third command, I suppose it's `--dport`. I tried those commands on the machine, and use `curl` to test, but unfortunately, no matter what URL I use, curl only complains "Connection refused". The log file of the local proxy server also indicates no connection was received.

Comment: Lets say user connects using destination port 8000/TCP, connection will be obviously refused because there is nothing listening on TCP 8000

Comment: Sorry I can't quite understand what should be listening on port 8000 (as in your example). Like if I use curl, my understanding is an arbitrary port is used to send the original request, then iptables will force it to go through the local proxy server listening on port 1080, next the proxy server (re-)sends the processed request using another port, either to the original target or the next node in the proxy chain.

Comment: Users coming throuhg any port, except TCP/1080 must be redirected to the proxy? If thats the case, your firewall DNAT rule must include a port range of 1024-65535

Comment: Not exactly. That machine is not a server, it's just a regular desktop PC I use every day. And there is a VPN-like application running on it. I just want to ensure all requests are processed before they are actually sent out. So there is nothing about inbound connections.

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. It makes sense now. Normally this behavior is application specific. For example, I can proxy all my HTTP(S) traffic to BurSuite before leaving my machine. To achieve this, I do not use iptables, but tune my web browser instead, to use a proxy located at 127.0.0.1  In your case, specify the proxy parameters (127.0.0.1:1080) to curl command.

Comment: Yes, but manually setting up the proxy for all the applications is not that easy, newly installed may be left out, some do not have built-in proxy support, and lots of system-bundled programs I even don't know their names. Also, I'm writing curl programs using C, the program itself already occupies the proxy slot, I still want it to go through my local proxy first then the one specified in the program.